# Amount of stamps for sending postcards from India

Tags: online-resources, mail

What value of stamp do I require to affix to a postcard which I plan on mailing from India to Croatia? Presumably it'd be the same as sending to anywhere in Europe?

Comment: Probably one. Since stamps are usually denominated corresponding to the price of most common postal services, you usually only need one stamp. If you actually meant to ask if there is a generic resource for different postal rates, I doubt that you will find one. Postal entities operate with enormous variations in theirs products and different class of services and in some countries there are several competing entities, making a comparison very difficult.

Comment: At least in Europe the value of stamps and not their amount is that what matters.

Comment: I believe the OP meant the value.. But he phrased it that way.

Comment: @mithy: There are only a few European countries issuing so called non-denominated stamps where the stamps do not have an exact monetary value, but are valid for a specific service.

Comment: Yeah, I meant value. And no, it is usually not the case that you only need one stamp. In some countries it comes up to 4-5 stamps per letter/postcard.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am an ex-India Post employee and we used to advise postage of Rs. 12 for International Post Cards, i.e. India to anywhere. I know few colleagues who encouraged stamps worth Rs. 15. Surface PostCard cost Rs. 4 to 7 while Airmail PostCard cost Rs. 12, except Pakistan, Bangladesh, Nepal and Bhutan which cost Rs. 8.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

[Indian Post Website](http://www.indiapost.gov.in/Postage/PostageCalculator.html) has a postage calculator which will show you the cost. Anyway most Post offices websites have this calculator feature.

Comment: Unfortunately, this website states wrong amount. It says that I should pay 7 rupees and the correct amount (after getting to post office and actually sending these postcards) is 15 rupees per postcard (two stamps - 10 and 5 rupee) and this amount is the same for all European countries and USA as well.